# Amp Script with HTML

Tags: ampscript

I am trying to create a email template in content builder using a HTML.I have to give the first name of the email recipient using Amp script.I wrote the Amp script code at the beginning of the HTML and template display the AMP script code.Why I see the Amp script code on the email template?

Answer (score 2):

Ampscript is rendered at send time and in the preview message context. While you are building your email, it would appear there. When you preview it, it would then render, provided that your syntax is correct and you are using a data extension that captures the necessary rationalization fields.

PS.

If you have a field called `First Name` in your source DE, then a personalisation string would be more appropriate i.e `%%First Name%%`.